# Best practices for viewmodels for SwiftUI preview?

Tags: mvvm, swift-language

Are there best practices about how to prepare lightweight viewmodels with dummy data, that could be used in SwiftUI previews?

Right now, I have a viewmodel for an in-app purchase screen, that needs to fetch products from the app store, but for mocking it in preview (without needing a whole fetching code), I added second `init()` that lets me just prefill all the properties, and put it inside `#if DEBUG` section to prevent accidentally calling it from production code.

However, this has forced me to have all the references to an app state (which I need to call loadproducts() on model) as an `optional var` (because dummy init doesn't set them) instead of `let` (which I'd prefer because then there is no chance of them being accidentally nil in production).

In other languages I could have abstract `ProductViewModelBase` (which would store and expose all properties the view needs), and from that a production `ProductViewModel` and dummy `DummyProductViewModel` (for previews) could inherit, but Swift doesn't have abstract classes.

While the following solution works and is fast, I am basically having two different classes in one, and distinguishing among them with nil properties, which feels like 'doing javascript in swift' instead of using the types to express semantics and disallow representation of invalid states :/.

Is there a better way?

**Example:**

ProductViewModel.swift

```
import Combine
import Foundation

class ProductViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published fileprivate(set) var isLoaded: Bool
    @Published fileprivate(set) var stateLabel: String
    
    @Published fileprivate(set) var product: MyProduct
    @Published fileprivate(set) var title: String = ""
    @Published fileprivate(set) var description: String = ""
    @Published fileprivate(set) var price: String = ""
    @Published fileprivate(set) var priceTimeUnit: String = ""

    public var transactionHandler: TransactionHandler?
    var transactionStateCancellable: AnyCancellable?

    init(transactionHandler: TransactionHandler, inAppPurchaseManager: InAppPurchaseManager, product: MyProduct) {
        self.transactionHandler = transactionHandler
        self.product = product
        
        self.isLoaded = false
        self.stateLabel = ""
                
        // all the loading etc.
        self.transactionStateCancellable = transactionHandler.$productsState.receive(on: RunLoop.main).sink { [weak self] newState in
            guard let self = self else { return }

            switch newState {
            case .initial:
                self.stateLabel = ""
            case .productsAreLoading:
                self.stateLabel = "Loading \(Constants.ELLIPSIS)"
            case .productsLoaded:
                self.stateLabel = ""
                self.isLoaded = true
            case .productsLoadingError:
                self.stateLabel = "Error loading products"
            }
            
            if let skProduct = inAppPurchaseManager.getAvailableProduct(id: product.id) {
                self.price = skProduct.formatProductPriceForButton()
                self.title = skProduct.localizedTitle
                self.description = product.description()
                self.priceTimeUnit = product.priceTimeUnit()
                self.isLoaded = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    #if DEBUG
    /// Dummy init for preview
    init(dummyProduct: MyProduct, title: String, price: String) {
        self.isLoaded = true
        self.stateLabel = "Product loaded"
        
        self.product = dummyProduct
        self.title = title
        self.description = dummyProduct.description()
        self.price = price
        self.priceTimeUnit = dummyProduct.priceTimeUnit()
    }
    #endif
}
```

I can then use it in preview:

```
struct ProductView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            // Calling dummy init
            ProductView(viewModel: ProductViewModel(dummyProduct: .monthlySub, title: "Monthly", price: "$0.99"))
        }
    }
}
```

While this is how it would be called in production:

```
// Calling real init()
ProductView(viewModel: ProductViewModel(transactionHandler: AppState.DummyAppState.transactionHandler, inAppPurchaseManager: AppState.DummyAppState.inAppPurchaseManager, product: .monthly))
    .environmentObject(AppState.DummyAppState)
    .environmentObject(WindowState.DummyWindowState)
```